# powershell, quoting rules in sub-expression substitution in strings

Tags: powershell

I recently when thru code looking like

```
$string="don't do that"
"'$($string -replace "'","''")'"
```

I always thought that the outermost string was first read, then checked for possible interpolation, but as the quoted code works, it' obviously not the case (sub-expression seems to be catch AND interpreted on the fly).

is this the expected behavior or an undocumented feature? where can I find the canonical definition of the quoting rules in sub-expressions?

Comment: The innermost expression has to be evaluated before you can evaluate the surrounding string expression, pretty straightforward. So yes, absolutely expected. It's a bit like reducing arithmetic operations - `$result = (1 + 2) + (3 + 4)` - you need to calculate both `1+2` and `3+4` before you can calculate the final result to store in `$result`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes, of course, subexpression must be evaluated to build the resultant string. but is it normal that the quotation mark count is reset while reading the subexpression? this mean that the outermost string reading process is suspended while the subexpression is executed in a new environment which reset the quotation mark count/behaviour.

Comment: There's no "quotation mark count" to be reset - the parser _recursively_ descends through the source code until it's produced a valid syntax tree, meaning that the parsing routine for `"'$($string -replace "'","''")'"` is "constant value `'` followed by a statement `$(...)` followed by a constant value `'`". The inner statement is parsed separately, so there's no "previously matching quotation mark" from the parent string literal expression to be confused about - because the parsing routine for `$($string -replace "'","''")` doesn't need to know about them.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks :-) make it an answer so I can vote for it.

Comment: @Peyre Done, hope it's sufficient :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question appears to arise from a misunderstanding of how PowerShell code is parsed and interpreted.

PowerShell code is not interpreted as a flat stream of instructions - instead, the phases of PowerShell's language infrastructure mimics the lifecycle model you'd find in most other modern dynamic programming languages:

1. Tokenization
2. Parsing
3. Compilation
4. Evaluation

So first, the code is tokenized (`"$(123)"` is split into a list of distinct "tokens", eg. `"`, `$(` `123`, `)` and `"`). The parser then [*recursively* descends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) through the source code token list until it's produced a valid and complete syntax tree.

Employing recursive descent means that the parsing routine (let's call it `ParseStringLiteral()`) for the string literal expression `"'$($string -replace "'","''")'"` goes like this:

1. Opening quote is `"` so we know it's an expandable string expression
2. The constant value `'` is consumed
3. `$(` is detected - since this is an expandable string literal the parser invokes a `ParseSubExpression`* routine which:

   - ... consumes input tokens until the matching `)` is encountered, and
   - ... returns an appropriate syntax tree element
4. The constant value `'` is consumed
5. The closing `"` is encountered, completing this string literal syntax element

*) *Note: the individual parsing routines are mutually recursive - `ParseSubExpression` will eventually call back into `ParseStringLiteral` - in this case once for `"'"` and once for `"''"`*

The result of parsing `"'$($string -replace "'","''")'"` is then a syntax tree with 3 child elements - a constant string value, another expression (the subexpression), and finally another constant value.

The parsing routine for the outer string literal therefore never encounters the `"'","''"` part of your source code - because those tokens will have already been consumed by the routine that parsed the subexpression by the time it reaches the closing `"` - all it needs to know is that the `ParseSubExpression` routine was able to produce a valid syntax element from the tokens it consumed from `$(` onwards, and that a closing `"` can be found further ahead in the token list (step 5 above).

---

Once the source code is parsed, PowerShell compiles the resulting AST to an *expression tree* - again, traversing the syntax tree depth-first, lowering or rewriting syntax elements to underlying instruction primitives in the process.

At runtime, the exact same type of tree traversal happens a third and final time - in order to evaluate the expression tree (which was produced by compiling the AST, which in turn was produced by parsing the source code `"'$($string -replace "'","''")'"`), PowerShell's runtime once again recursively descends through the expression tree and keeps evaluating and collapsing leaf nodes until it can calculate the actual resulting string value of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

To offer a *succinct summary* of [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful, technically detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77680349/45375):

- A `$(...)` [subexpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) - whether embedded in an [expandable (interpolating), double-quoted string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) or not - is a *separate, independent parsing context* that may contain any number of statements.

  - When a `"..."` string literal is evaluated at runtime, any embedded subexpressions are replaced with the (stringified) *result of their evaluation*, i.e. their output (e.g., `"$(2 + 2) equals 4"`; ditto for the *values* of simple embedded *variable references* (e.g, `"$HOME is the home dir."`
- In other words: The *literal* parts of a `"..."` string *should* have no bearing on any embedded subexpressions (`$(...)`) and the subexpression should be parsed the same as outside of an expandable string. While that is  *generally* true, there are a few ***bugs***, as of PowerShell 7.4:

  - Note:

    - All these bugs seem to be manifestations of the fact that embedded `$(...)` constructs are de facto *not* treated like an entirely separate parsing context, and are affected by the initial parsing of the enclosing `"..."` string.
    - The `"`-related bugs can be *worked around* by escaping the `$(...)`-embedded `"` chars. as `` `" `` - but, of course, these workarounds will break should the bugs ever get fixed.
    - A future-proof workaround - which is the only option for the `)`-related bug - is to use *nested subexpressions* based on `[char]` casts to produce the desired characters; e.g.:

      ```bash
      # Workaround for: "$("Nat `"King`" Cole")"
      # Yields «Nat "King" Cole»
      "$("Nat $([char] 34)King$([char] 34) Cole")"

      # Workaround for: "$(')')"
      # Yields «)»
      "$([char] 41)" # if part of a larger string: "$("$([char] 41)")"
      ```
  - [Probably won't get fixed] [GitHub issue #3039](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3039#issuecomment-353224924):

    ```bash
    # Unexpected removal of a " char.
    # Should yield «a""b» , but is «a"b»
    "$('a""b')"
    ```
  - [Not reported separately]:

    ```bash
    # Unexpected failure: "Unexpected token 'King`" Cole"' in expression or statement."
    # Should yield «Nat "King" Cole»
    "$("Nat `"King`" Cole")"
    ```
  - [MAY get fixed] [GitHub issue #4543](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4543):

    ```bash
    # Unexpected failure: "The string is missing the terminator."
    # Should yield «)»
    "$(')')"
    ```
  - As an aside: There's at least one more expandable-string bug, albeit not related to subexpressions: [GitHub issue #13707](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13707)

    ```bash
    # The first env. var. reference is unexpectedly ignored,
    # because the two environment-variable references are directly
    # concatenated with ":"
    # The example assumes execution on Windows.
    # Should yield, e.g., «Windows_NTjdoe», but yields just «jdoe»
    "$env:OS:$env:USERNAME"
    ```